# Микросервисная архитектура, SpringBoot, Zuul

Tags: java, архитектура, spring-boot, микросервисы, zuul

Помогите понять как это должно выглядеть и работать. У меня есть `gateway` и есть сервис который занимается бизнес логикой (для примера хватит одного, в проекте их больше). Я хочу сделать что бы `gateway` занимался проверкой прав у того или иного юзера и вообще занимался определением юзера.
В обычном монолите я бы просто навесил свою какую то аннотацию (`@RolesAllowed, @FeaturesAllowed`) на метод контроллера

```
@GetMapping(path = "/some-path")
@RolesAllowed("USER")
@FeaturesAllowed({"PRINT"});
public Object getSomeObject(UserState userState) {
    // do something with data from user state
    return null;
}
```

Но как должна выглядеть эта проверка на уровне `gateway`? Ведь там навешивать аннотации не на что, и делать получается только через фильтра?

И еще одна не понятная мне вешь для проверки всей нужной информации в `gateway` мне необходим `UserState`, за которым я полезу в базу, но этот же `UserState` мне нужен и в контроллерах микросервисов, для получения той же id юзера и еще кое какой информации. Мне его нужно передавать из `gateway` или же формировать его непосредственно в самом микросервисе?  Откуда должен браться этот `UserState` в методах контроллера?

Comment: Что есть gateway? nginx?

Comment: @hedgehogues gateway являеется `Zuul`

Comment: Почему нельзя редирект поставить на соответствующий сервис (если сервиса нет, то создать таковой)?

Comment: @hedgehogues не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду? Вы имеете ввиду редирект поставить для проксирования ? и зачем если как мне казалось этим должен заниматься gateway